# Why doesn't ServerFault do a better job of finding interesting questions?

Tags: feature-request

I've always wondered why Server Fault (and I guess all SE sites) don't do a better job of showing questions that are interesting to *me*.

The site already knows a lot about me like:

- Tags I find interesting
- Tags with wikis that I edit
- Tags I don't find interesting
- Questions I ask
- Questions I answer
- Questions I comment on
- Tags and questions I vote on

And the site knows a lot about the questions:

- Questions with high votes
- Question age
- Questions without answers or accepted answers
- ## of views

Yet with all that information, the main page and Questions page seem a little dumb. At least it would be nice to have an "Interesting" tab that used the above information to find questions I might prefer to interact with.  It would certainly beat having to click through tags or spend time searching.

Answer (score 8):

I didn't realize I'd have to go back 10 pages on the blog to find this post again:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

I guess they are still deciding whether to roll this out to other sites.

Personally, I rely on the "keep refreshing the new questions page and hope I see something I like" method.

Comment: Same. I don't think this new layout would help Server Fault as our question rate isn't fast enough.

Comment: About once a month, I'll click through all my favourite tags to see if I missed anything, but there's never going to be a lot of VMS activity.

Comment: Ok, WTH.  Did I read that blog post at some point and it just bubbled up in my head today?? I feel like this is INCEPTION or something. :)

Comment: Also, I think that would work but the last activity would need to be tweaked.